# Random smooth graph

Tags: c#, math, graph

I want to have graph similar to graph on the picture below. I want to achieve graph similar to cos/sin, but with a bit of randomness. Graph should never go over(100) or below(0) limit.
Without randomness we can write function like this:

```
f(x)=cos(x)*50+50
```

[image: Random graph]

I'm looking for implementation in any language or just a simple explanation.

Comment: For what purpose?  This is a bit too open-ended ...

Comment: @RBarryYoung generating random terrain for a simple game.

Comment: Ah, OK.  As I recall, random terrain is best generated as a combination of f(0) and f(1) processes ...

Comment: Do you want a) to generate a set of points, b) an analytic function, c) a graphing tool?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply sum a few sin/cos with random coefficients and periods.

**Implementation example:**

```
internal struct SineWave
{
    internal readonly double Amplitude;
    internal readonly double OrdinaryFrequency;
    internal readonly double AngularFrequency;
    internal readonly double Phase;
    internal readonly double ShiftY;

    internal SineWave(double amplitude, double ordinaryFrequency, double phase, double shiftY)
    {
        Amplitude = amplitude;
        OrdinaryFrequency = ordinaryFrequency;
        AngularFrequency = 2 * Math.PI * ordinaryFrequency;
        Phase = phase;
        ShiftY = shiftY;
    }
}

public class RandomCurve
{
    private SineWave[] m_sineWaves;

    public RandomCurve(int components, double minY, double maxY, double flatness)
    {
        m_sineWaves = new SineWave[components];

        double totalPeakToPeakAmplitude = maxY - minY;
        double averagePeakToPeakAmplitude = totalPeakToPeakAmplitude / components;

        int prime = 1;
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < components; i++)
        {
            // from 0.5 to 1.5 of averagePeakToPeakAmplitude 
            double peakToPeakAmplitude = averagePeakToPeakAmplitude * (r.NextDouble() + 0.5d);

            // peak amplitude is a hald of peak-to-peak amplitude
            double amplitude = peakToPeakAmplitude / 2d;

            // period should be a multiple of the prime number to avoid regularities
            prime = Utils.GetNextPrime(prime);
            double period = flatness * prime;

            // ordinary frequency is reciprocal of period
            double ordinaryFrequency = 1d / period;

            // random phase
            double phase = 2 * Math.PI * (r.NextDouble() + 0.5d);

            // shiftY is the same as amplitude
            double shiftY = amplitude;

            m_sineWaves[i] =
                new SineWave(amplitude, ordinaryFrequency, phase, shiftY);
        }
    }

    public double GetY(double x)
    {
        double y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_sineWaves.Length; i++)
            y += m_sineWaves[i].Amplitude * Math.Sin(m_sineWaves[i].AngularFrequency * x + m_sineWaves[i].Phase) + m_sineWaves[i].ShiftY;

        return y;
    }
}

internal static class Utils
{
    internal static int GetNextPrime(int i)
    {
        int nextPrime = i + 1;
        for (; !IsPrime(nextPrime); nextPrime++) ;
        return nextPrime;
    }

    private static bool IsPrime(int number)
    {
        if (number == 1) return false;
        if (number == 2)  return true;

        for (int i = 2; i < number; ++i)
            if (number % i == 0) return false;

        return true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: with random periods too, I assume?

Answer (score 2):

So here is a code written in C#, it can be randomized more with random input values.
I just give you some output with values to see if it's okay for you. Amplite can be modified for the cosinus and sinus values. The offset is added in the end (so min value is always 0) and the scaling is done to be sure the max value is 100. As you can see noise can be added to (figure 3, figure 4).

> terr1: RandomTerrarain(1000, 4,  1, 10, 5, 0);
>   [Figure 1](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/64369382/terr1.png)
>
> terr2: RandomTerrarain(1000, 2,  3, -10, 5, 0);
>   [Figure 2](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/64369382/terr2.png)

Hope this helps!

```
      private static Random rnd = new Random();
    private double[] RandomTerrarain(int length, int sinuses, int cosinuses, double amplsin, double amplcos, double noise)
    {
        if (length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", length, "Length must be greater than zero!");
        double[] returnValues = new double[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            // sin
            for (int sin = 1; sin <= sinuses; sin++)
            {
                returnValues[i] += amplsin * Math.Sin((2 * sin * i * Math.PI) / (double)length);
            }
            // cos
            for (int cos = 1; cos <= cosinuses; cos++)
            {
                returnValues[i] += amplcos * Math.Cos((2 * cos * i * Math.PI) / (double)length);
            }
            // noise
            returnValues[i] += (noise * rnd.NextDouble()) - (noise * rnd.NextDouble());
        }
        // give offset so it be higher than 0
        double ofs = returnValues.Min();
        if (ofs < 0)
        {
            ofs *= -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                returnValues[i] += ofs;
            }
        }
        // resize to be fit in 100
        double max = returnValues.Max();
        if (max >= 100)
        {
            double scaler = max / 100.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                returnValues[i] /= scaler;
            }
        }
        return returnValues;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your function, you can use [`Math`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zfefwz9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and [`Cos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
public static double GetCosFunction(double d)
{
     return Math.Cos(d) * 50 + 50;
}
```

For graph solution, you can check these topics;

- http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/a-mathematical-graphing-application-in-c-sharp/
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32836/A-simple-C-library-for-graph-plotting
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/tags/Math-Graph-in-C%23

Comment: I think that you misunderstand the question.  He was not asking how to graph that function, he was asking how to make that function more random.

Comment: What is that mean "making function more random" ? Functions works clear input and clear output. How could be a function more random works only with an expression called `cos(x)*50+50` ? Please light me..

Comment: He wants a function similar to that function but that has some randomness to it.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot this....

> terr3: RandomTerrarain(1000, 5,  5, -2, 5, 2);
>   [Figure 3](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/64369382/terr3.png)
>
> terr4: RandomTerrarain(1000, 4, 1, 5, -20, 1);
>   [Figure 4](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/64369382/terr4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [xkcd-style graphs](http://dan.iel.fm/xkcd/), a method to add random noise to a graph and smooth it in a way to make it look hand-drawn, imitating the style of the [xkcd cartoons](http://xkcd.com/). Whilst this isn't exactly what you want, I think simply setting the input graph to zero (e.g. y=0) and tweaking the noise smoothing parameters to much larger noise amplitude and much larger smoothing distance will probably result in the kind of random graph you are looking for.